# How to allow JSON post (and later get) only "time" (not date/timestamp) property of resource

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, jpa

Creating API to allow JSON POST of "resource" with persistence to backend.

Have one of the property which is basically a "time" of the day (format 2.00 PM, 5.00 PM etc). Trying to explore various options of either passing it as plain String or text (from rest client) OR should be of any specific "time" format easy for api implementation to accept it(easy mapping/parsing). Looking for suggestions ?

Sample Json:

```
{

   "name" : "Mark",
   "age" : 15,
   "cutOffTime": "2.00 PM" (????)
   ........

}
```

Comment: The recommended format will be ISO 8601, particularly `HH:mm` (`14:00`) or an extended format such as `HH:mm:ss`.

Comment: Thanks for posting. the main question is how it (cutOffTime) should be persisted in say Oracle tables along with Resource (should it be text or timestamp - it is just oracle doe not have just TIME), so that it can be later useful to be used as a criteria , both in native queries (like pull records before cutOffTime for table) & in JPA?

Answer (score 1):

## Go for [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html)

The [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) which was first introduced with [Java SE 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) and has been further enriched in the subsequent releases, provides a rich set of API to manage date, time and their formatting. Given below is a demo of the same:

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test strings
        String[] strTimes = { "1:00", "01:00", "1:00 pm", "1:00 am", "01:00 am", "01:00 pm", "13:10", "8:9", "8:9 am" };

        // Define the formatter
        DateTimeFormatter inputFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                            .parseCaseInsensitive()
                                            .appendPattern("[h:m a][H:m]")
                                            .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);

        DateTimeFormatter outputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");

        for (String strTime : strTimes) {
            LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(strTime, inputFormatter);

            // String to be displayed or saved into the database
            String formattedTime = time.format(outputFormatter);
            System.out.println(formattedTime);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
01:00
01:00
13:00
01:00
01:00
13:00
13:10
08:09
08:09
```

It was error-prone as well as complex to do the same thing using the legacy date-time API. For your requirement, I recommend you use `LocalTime` (this is why I've chosen `LocalTime` in the demo). You can learn more about the modern date-time API from [**Trail: Date Time**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)

Comment: ok, suppose have Oracle database to store the resource (on POST), as Oracle to my knowledge have no datatype specially just for "Time" (it has timestamp which store date along), hence going by the answer, should also store "cutOffTime" as "string" (text)?     It is that once time is saved along with resource, it would be used as criteria to pull data from other tables (where clause), say for example - get only records from TableXYZ before cutoff time for that day, so was trying to store it in a format that is understandable both by native queries and jpa?

Comment: @ArpitS - In this case, you can simply save `time` (not `formattedTime`) into the DB. Check [this article](https://thorben-janssen.com/map-date-time-api-jpa-2-2/) to learn more about using `LocalTime` with JPA.

Comment: Thanks for your post. Have no issue with upvote/accepting the answer, any suggestion is very much appreciated. Let me try to explain the problem one more time. Basically, the Oracle version 12 used for persisting resource does not gives me option to define TIME datatype (its unsupported, only timestamp is supported) and when I use LocalTime in Entity and persist the resource, the cutOffTime get saved as timestamp (date and time). The 'cutOffTime'(for eg 2:00 PM) will remain constant for resource, it would be used though later in native queries(or JPA) as criteria to pull data from other tables

Comment: @ArpitS - You can use `LocalDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime` in that case. I do not have a link to a page for Oracle JDBC Driver at the moment but you can check [this page for PostgreSQL JDBC Driver](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/8-date-time.html). You can always get just time part from the timestamp and do all calculations. When it comes to printing just the time or getting a time string from the `LocalDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime`, you can use the same `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm")` as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: for now preferring to store as plain text in either 24 hr format or 12, and then creating timestamp for comparison like this - select to_timestamp(to_char(sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD')||' '||cutoff_time_2, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') from mytable;

Comment: @ArpitS - Great! Choose the approach which suits your requirement. In the end, what matters is your problem should be solved.